# How to allow a google apps script to be executed in the pubhtml version?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

To give context.

I have recently made a Character Sheet, with the gimmick being that they randomly change form. I have made a script that allows one to click a button and a new form will be randomly generated from a hidden sheet.

Now, I wanted to publish it so that the group could access it without the whole Sheets interface in the way.

The question is thus. Is it possible to make the button executeable for everyone in the pubhtml version ?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is `a google apps script to be executed in the pubhtml version`? 2. Can I ask you about the current issue of your script?

Comment: @Tanaike It is a Google sheet published: url ending in `/pubhtml`. OP wants to execute a script from a button in the published  version.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. From your comment, I understood that OP had wanted to run Google Apps Script on the web published Google Spreadsheet. In that case, unfortunately, I also think that it cannot be achieved as you mentioned in your answer. It is required to use the publicly shared Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: @Tanaike About publicly shared Google spreadsheet, OP wants to avoid sheets interface: *Now, I wanted to publish it so that the group could access it without the whole Sheets interface in the way.* So, completely impossible.

Comment: So, to clarify. You can't make a button that works on a published version ? Because that is basically what I want.

Comment: @OVERANGELDROPTHEBEAT Yes. What you want is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, It is not possible to start execution of any apps scripts from the published url of Google sheets: `/pubhtml` using buttons or otherwise.

However, it is possible to execute scripts in a Google sheet using [time driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) and have the changes published as per the refresh rate configured.